# How to set multiple routes to same action method in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am working on single page application using MVC 5 and Angular 2.

My requirment is I need do set multiple routes to same  controller/action method.

If user enters url http://localhost:xxxx/home/index , it will target "index" action method of "home" controller.

I also
want "http://localhost:xxxx/products" and "http://localhost:xxxx/categories" to point to "index" action method of "home" controller.

Note : Both "products" and "categories" are netiher controller or action methods.

Comment: If they're not controllers or action methods what are they?

Comment: They are my client side angular 2 routes , the problem i am facing is when users refreshes the browser , it will display 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding below 2 routes did the job.

```
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "categories",
          url: "categories",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "products",
          url: "products",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );


       routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: This works , but can't we define a single route instead of 2 routes ?

Comment: What if Home should point to Home controller or any other url should point to their respective controller and action.Only Categories and product should both point to product controller.

Comment: I would like this to be dynamic, i mean I do not want to define the multiple routes for each value ("products" and "categories" in this case) instead want to get same from the database. Is there any way for same?